# How to inner join two windowed tables in Flux query language?

Tags: database, join, influxdb, flux-influxdb

The goal is to join tables `min` and `max` returned by the following query:

```
data = from(bucket: "my_bucket")
    |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)

min = data
    |> aggregateWindow(
        every: 1d, 
        fn: min,
        column: "_value")

max = data
    |> aggregateWindow(
        every: 1d, 
        fn: max,
        column: "_value")
```

The columns of `max` look like this:

```
+---------------------------------+
|             Columns             |
+---------------------------------+
| table MAX                       |
| _measurement GROUP STRING       |
| _field GROUP STRING             |
| _value NO GROUP DOUBLE          |
| _start GROUP DATETIME:RFC3339   |
| _stop GROUP DATETIME:RFC3339    |
| _time NO GROUP DATETIME:RFC3339 |
| env GROUP STRING                |
| path GROUP STRING               |
+---------------------------------+
```

The `min` table looks the same except the name of the first column. Both tables return data which can be confirmed by running `yield(tables:min)` or `yield(tables:max)`. The join should be an inner join on columns `_measurement`, `_field`, `_time`, `env` and `path` and it should contain both the minimum and the maximum value `_value` of every window.

When I try to run within influxdb DataExplorer

```
join(tables: {min: min, max: max}, on: ["_time", "_field", "path", "_measurement", "env"], method: "inner")
```

I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute Flux query
```

When I run the job in Bash via `influx query --file ./query.flux -r > ./query.csv;` I get the following error:

```
Error: failed to execute query: 504 Gateway Timeout: unable to decode response content type "text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

No more logging-output is available to investigate the issue further. Whats wrong with this join?

Answer (score 0):

join can only take two tables as the parameters according to this [doc](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/join/). You could try the union where it can take more than two tables as the input. See more details [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/union/).

You might just need to modify the script as below:

```
union(tables: [min: min, max: max]
```